# How can I make my app launch faster?

Tags: android

I am experimenting with an app I am developping.

When I launch the app, there is currently a 3 second delay before the app UI is usable. During the delay the screen is black, apart from the task bar and, below it, the app title bar.

I was thinking about displaying a splashscreen as a dialog in the main Activity. However, it is only displayed after those 3 seconds, which makes it useless. This means that nearly all of the 3-second delay takes place between the launch and the call to

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState).
```

Can anyone educate me on what is happening behing the scenes during this delay ? Is there anything I can do to shorten it ?

Comment: Which `on*` functions have you implemented? Have you checked if there is code which is slow?

Comment: are you doing any lengthy operations (network connections) on the ui/event thread?

Comment: Well, I did some more accurate timing. It takes 1.45 s to run from the start of onCreate to the start of onResume (including 1.23s to parse a file). Then 0.62 s to the first onDraw. The parsing is in the UI thread because it is used to populate an ArrayAdapter. I tried unsuccessfully to move to a separate thread but it was messing my adapter indexing and filtering. I guess I'll have to try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to locate the slow code and put it into a second thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // slow code goes here.
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: I though there could be other reasons apart from my code... So I'm the culprit ! I thought a lot of processing could happen between the launch and the call to onCreate. But then.. not.